# Octave - Excel - Xlsread reads Nan instead of text

Tags: octave, xlsread

The Universities spread sheat in Excel include:

```
ID & University Name
0    Mechanical Engineering
1    Civil Engineering

filename = 'test.xlsx';
sheet = 'Universities';
xlRange = 'A2:B31'; 
UniversityNames = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange);
```

but when I display universitynames matrix. I can see ID number but university Name is displayed as `'NaN'`. I need to see names of university in this `UniversityNames` matrix. How can I fix this? OS is Windows 10, Excel 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Octave's [`xlsread` function](https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/function/xlsread.html) has multiple outputs. The first output returned is the numeric data from the input range, which is what you're currently reading in as `UniversityNames`. The optional second output returns the text strings from the input range, which I'm assuming is what you're looking for. You can also utilize the optional third output, which returns a cell array of the raw strings from the input range.

```
filename = 'test.xlsx';
sheet = 'Universities';
xlRange = 'A2:B31'; 
[UniversityNames_numeric, UniversityNames_textual] = xlsread(filename, sheet, xlRange);
```

Or

```
filename = 'test.xlsx';
sheet = 'Universities';
xlRange = 'A2:B31'; 
[~, ~, rawdata] = xlsread(filename, sheet, xlRange);
```

Comment: Thanks @excaza . But now when i display UniversityNames_textual i receive UniversityNames_textual = { [1,1] = Mechanical Engineering [2,1] = Civil Engineering } Why does it displays like this ? I only need Names, what are 1,1 and 2,1 and why does it shown with { }